# Change the context language according to the country location in android

Tags: android

I am doing a project, it is going to finish but I am facing a problem to release the project. Right now, the context of the project is in English. But the requirement is like, according to the country location the context will be changed e.g Japanese, Spanish, Chinese etc. So my concern question is how to do that?
Foe English I have written like:

```
   <string name="bookedittext">EDIT</string>
    <string name="button_delete">Delete</string>
    <string name="button_delete_cancel">Cancel</string>
    <string name="button_back">Back</string>
    <string name="progress_deleting">Deleting...</string>
    <string name="share_message_conf_delete">Do you want to delete?</string>
    <string name="share_message_conf_delete_all">Do you want to delete all?</string>
    <string name="TEXT_SHARE_VIA">Share Via</string>
    <string name="TEXT_CONTENT">Image content</string>
    <string name="TEXT_SELECT_APPLICATION">Select an Application</string>
    <string name="TEXT_MORE_OPTIONS">More Options</string>
    <string name="TEXT_FACEBOOK">Facebook</string>
    <string name="TEXT_KAKAO_TALK">Kakao Talk</string>
    <string name="TEXT_SKYPE">Skype</string>
    <string name="TEXT_KIK">Kik Messanger</string>
    <string name="TEXT_FRING">Fring Messenger</string>
    <string name="TEXT_TWITTER">Twitter</string>
    <string name="TEXT_YAHOO">Yahoo Messenger</string>
    <string name="TEXT_USE_FOR_DEFAULT">Use this by default action</string>
    <string name="TEXT_USE_FOR_BACK">Back</string>
```

Please help me how to convert these to Japanese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple resouce files, for different locales.
Read

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html.

Comment: I created the strings.xml file with in values-ja folder but how it will dynamically set to the application?

Comment: If device locale is ja, your app will use values-ja folder, and so on.